# Pattern and Regular Expression in nltk

Tags: python, nltk

I have the following String with the structure:
"Film name is American directed by name"
I want to define a pattern using regular expressions in nltk to  extract soemthing like this
[('the film name')]
('is')
[('american')]
('directed by')
[('name')]

Could you please help in defining the pattern, I am new to python and nltk.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Posting this in case anyone find it helpfull:

```
 pattern= re.match( r'(.*) is (.*?) directed by (.*?).*', item, re.M|re.I)
```

in this pattern the result will be:

```
pattern.group(1): film name
pattern.group(2): category
pattern.group(3): director name
```

Comment: Sorry but the problem in your question is way harder than what you can do with a single regular expression (or even with many). There must be a textbook to go with the assignment, read it.